# Access CVAT connected file share from NFS mounted storage

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, nfs, cvat

I have mounted an Azure Storage container to an Ubuntu 18.04 VM following [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support-how-to).
Then I updated docker compose file (docker-compose.override.yml) by following CVAT [Computer Vision Annotation Tool](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat) [official documentation](https://openvinotoolkit.github.io/cvat/docs/administration/basics/installation/#share-path) for mounting share storage to CVAT docker and [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver_opts) as follows:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  cvat:
    environment:
      CVAT_SHARE_URL: 'Mounted from /mnt/share host directory'
    volumes:
      - cvat_share:/home/django/share:ro

volumes:
  cvat_share:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      device: ":/mnt/share"
      o: "addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft,rw"
```

Then I install CVAT following [installation guide](https://openvinotoolkit.github.io/cvat/docs/administration/basics/installation/#ubuntu-1804-x86_64amd64). But we I try to run the CVAT docker using the command `docker-compose up -d`, getting following error:

```
ERROR: for cvat  Cannot create container for service cvat: failed to mount local volume: mount :/mnt/share:/opt/docker/volumes/cvat_cvat_share/_data, data: addr=10.40.0.199,nolock,soft: operation not supported

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I tried different changes in the config file, but no luck. The [CVAT documentation](https://openvinotoolkit.github.io/cvat/docs/administration/advanced/mounting_cloud_storages/#microsoft-azure-container-as-filesystem) says you can mount the cloud storage as FUSE and use it later as share. But does it only support fuse protocol? How can I use a cloud storage mounted using NFS protocol in CVAT tool?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try with NFS but I faced a similar issue with GCSFuse to mount Google Cloud Storage.

What worked for me is to mount through fstab, let's say `/mnt/cvat` for the sake of the example, and then edit the `docker-compose.override.yml` file as follows,

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  cvat:
    environment:
      CVAT_SHARE_URL: 'Mounted from /mnt/share host directory'
    volumes:
      - cvat_share_bbal:/home/django/share/cvat:ro

volumes:
  cvat_share_bbal:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /mnt/cvat
      o: bind
```

When I had the device mounted at `/home/django/share` django was giving me errors.